# Hover over a row and affect the same "n" row of other tables

Tags: css, css-tables

[image]

I want to hover over a row and apply the hover styles to the same "n" row of other tables. Can I do this with pure CSS, without using javascript or jquery? All tables have the same number of rows

I attach an image in paint so that you better understand the question.

If it can't, the alternative solution would be with ngclass and javascript

```
<table class="maintable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table class="childtable1">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table class="childtable2">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table class="childtable3">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML.

Comment: I have updated with a simple example of how my code is.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible with pure css.

In css on hover you can achieve

1. inner elements of the hovered element
2. following sibling elements of the hovered elements

In your case you need to achieve

1. the parents table
   (which is not possible in pure css)
2. than parents td of parents table
   (which is not possible in pure css)
3. and than you could select down from there a following sibling and than childs
   (which indeed would be possible down from there)

**Description of sibling selectors**
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

**THINKING FORWARD...***

As of that rules: if you would change your html structure only using divs (just siblings) and style them with classes (i.e. `tbl1_row1`, `tbl2_row1`, ...) it would be possible.

As you only use tables with only one column ... maybe that could be a solution for you?

---

**Update 1:**  I have been to fast. The idea only would work if you hover a div-table-row in the first div-table and highlight the according rows in the following tables ... of course. You can not hover a div-table-row and in second or third div-table and achieve the first div-table. Same game as explained before of course. So the answer indeed: not possible and up to now no idea vor a possible html structure up from here :-(

---

**Update 2**
Added a link with description how sibling selectors work.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you would need to use Javascript to effect the background of cells in another table. CSS does not have a way of you getting back up to a parent, across and down again.

When the user hovers over a td in one of the 3 tables maintable has a class tdn added to it where n is 0-2 (in this case, it could be to any number of tds in the row). This causes the background color of the relevant tds to change, whatever inner table they are part of.

```js
  const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table table');
  const mainTable = document.querySelector('.maintable');
  for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    let tds = tables[i].querySelectorAll('tr td');
    for (let j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
      let td = tds[j];
      td.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
      mainTable.classList = 'maintable td' + j;
      });
    }
  }
```

```css
table.maintable.td0 tr td table tr:nth-child(1) td, table.maintable.td1 tr td table tr:nth-child(2) td, table.maintable.td2 tr td table tr:nth-child(3) td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="maintable">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table class="childtable1">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table class="childtable2">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="childtable3">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the very specific case that is shown in the question, where it is known that the rows are at the same vertical level you can achieve something like the desired effect purely in CSS - but as it's not a general solution it's given here more as a piece of fun.

The idea uses a pseudo element on each td in the 3 inner tables. These are given position absolute with the first ancestor going back up that has a position being the maintable. It is therefore possible to create a pseudo element which spans the whole width, covering the 3 innertables. These inner tables are separated by white borders.

```html
<head>
<style>

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.maintable {
width: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
table {
  border: none;
}
table table {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 2em;
  border-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.maintable tr td table tr td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid;
}

table.maintable tr td table tr td:hover:before {
  content: '';
  transform: translateY(-1em);
  height: 3.5em;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: -1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="maintable">
<tr>
    <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <table class="childtable1">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <table class="childtable2">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <table class="childtable3">
            <tr>
                <td> Row 1 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 2 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Row 3 of childtable3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```